# How to print the contents of a generic linked list?

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to print the content of my generic linked list called Transactions, but the output is "Task3.Transaction". The generic linked list has the class Transaction as its datatype because I am using the Transaction class to create nodes in the linked list.

Here is my code:

*The part in my code where the issue is has *** on both sides of it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkedList<Transaction> Transactions = new LinkedList<Transaction>(); //create the generic linked list

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=melss002; Initial Catalog=30001622; Integrated Security=True"); //Connection string

    int accNum = Int32.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter account number", "Account Number")); //Prompt the user for account number


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Transactions where AccountNo = " + accNum, con); //command to execute
    con.Open();  //open the connection to the database           
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    if (reader.HasRows)//Check if the table has records
    {
        while (reader.Read()) //read all records with the given AccountNo
        {
            Transaction Transaction001 = new Transaction(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetDateTime(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetDouble(4)); //New Transaction node
            Transactions.AddFirst(Transaction001);// add the node to the Doubly Linked List (Transactions)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No records found");
    }

    PrintNodes(Transactions);

    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}

public void PrintNodes(LinkedList<Transaction> values)
{
    if (values.Count != 0)
    {
        txtOutput.Text += "Here are your transaction details:";

        **foreach (Transaction t in values)**
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" + t;
        }
        txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        txtOutput.Text += "The Doubly Linked List is empty!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you overwritten the `.ToString()` method for `Transaction` class?

Comment: Please add the `Transaction` class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert an instance of a type (except `string`) to a string, such as when you:

> ```
> txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" + t;
> ```

the CLR (.NET runtime) will call the method `ToString()` on the passed object. This is a method that all types derived from `System.Object` (there are very few types in .NET not derived from `Object`) inherit.

But the default implementation just returns the name of the type.

You need to override `Object.ToString()` in your type. and return a more meaningful string.

Eg.

```
public class Transaction {
  //...
  public override string ToString() {
    // Guess field names from constructor:
    //  new Transaction(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetDateTime(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetDouble(4))

    return String.Format("#{0}: {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", id, timestamp, string1, string2, number);
  }
  // ...
```

Ideally an overflow talking an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IFormatProvider.aspx) and passing that through to formatting functions should also be present (and will be used by `String.Format` and such methods if available). Even better to implement [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bk5yxz0f.aspx).

Comment: Okay thank you very much! that makes absolute sense.

Comment: I've undone the edit that was just changing the formatting: it added nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Override the ToString method in the Transaction class.
By default it outputs the name of the type. This happens implicitly when you call this:

```
txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" + t;
```